# Using ui:repeat JSF2.0 to trace over a 'Set'

Tags: jsf-2

I want to use

```
<ui:repeat >
```

to trace over a collection of type 'Set', but unable to do so. If anybody has a solution, please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui:repeat` can't iterate over a `java.util.Set`

You can overcome it by doing something like this (convert your set into list and use it in your `ui:repeat`)

```
public List retrieveListAsSet(Set set) {
   return new ArrayList(set);
}
```

Or implemet your own `repeater` like described in this blog [Bozho's tech blog : How to Iterate Over java.util.Set in JSF](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=28)